# Docker container keeps showing Restarting(255)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm facing a notable issue regarding Docker container on EC2 Linux instance. I deployed them 5 months ago and it was running perfectly. But now they stop working.

I have deployed three Docker containers of Cockroach DB, Redis associated with TheThingStack (TheThingsIndustries) using Docker Compose. I tried restarting containers using Docker Compose but it gave me an error for no space remaining. So I suggest and confirmed it later on that my EBS storage of the EC2 instance got full.

So I extended the file system of Linux after increasing EBS storage size from AWS official guideline. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

But still its not restarting and gave me error of "No space". I tried last time by restarting single container of deployed containers using Docker Compose, and now its showing Restarting(255).

I'm attaching multiple pictures of it, maybe it will help anyone answer that.

[image: Space usage]

[image: Container showing Restarting]

[image: Error on restarting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was the issue. Sometimes you need to restart the EC2 machine, and I did that then the error was gone. All things are now working well.

As I increased the EBS storage, it showed the increased volume but the file system of Linux didn't increase, the only option I got left was to restart the EC2 machine and the error was gone after restarting the EC2 machine.